# Win10 New Error Message: Wi-Fi Access Point and Wi-Fi Access Point are on different Wi-Fi channels

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I did a Google search but it didn't return any related result. When I choose a SSID to connect, it shows the below error message, but I am still able to get online, what does it mean actually?
[image]

Comment: Are you connected to two different access points with the same internet but on two different channels? Example AP 1 on channel 11 AP 2 on channel 13 one connected via Ethernet and the other WiFi? or what is the setup could you please provide some more details.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Yes, you are right, I use channels 1,6,11 for multiple AP to cover a floor area, those should be non-overlapping channel, is it a bad idea to do so?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/7G3Lv.png

Comment: I have an idea change your AP to the same SSID and keep the channels how they are. 1,6,11 do not over lap but I would keep the AP all the same so as you roam around the floor area you would have no issues with connecting. This may fix your problem. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: before you do that change 25-AP6 to channel 1